# C++ - Como criar uma janela no windows

Tags: c++, gui, winapi

Estou começando a programar para windows usando c++ e o programa DevC++. Como faço para criar uma janela comum?

Comment: No site da MS, tem um tutorial de como criar e gerenciar as janelas em C++ utilizando a API do Windows (tradução automática): https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp

Comment: Recomendo não usar o DevC++ pois seu projeto foi abandonado a tempos, recomendo usar o visual studio community https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/vs/community/ (Esta versão é gratuita) que na minha opinião é a melhor IDE para C/C++ do mundo, ou usar o viusal studio code que é multiplataforma https://code.visualstudio.com/ e é mai leve (Menos de 100MB), porém vai ter que usar um compilador externo como GCC ou G++ (MinGW e Cygwin são exemplos).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Recomendo pesquisar sobre QT, Que é um framework multiplataforma para desenvolvimento de interfaces gráficas em C++. Com ele você pode fazer programas que funcionem tanto no Windows quanto no Linux e MacOS.
Caso queira aprender sobre QT, existem vários tutoriais na internet, em vários forums ou até mesmo pelo Stackoverflow na Tag "QT".

Conheça tambem o site oficial do QT (https://www.qt.io/) e veja todas as suas possibilidades.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode seguir [este tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb384843.aspx) usando Windows API mas não é recomendado pois é limitado, o ideal seria usar [Qt](https://www.qt.io/download) pois é multiplataforma, tem muitos recursos para criação de janela incluindo um editor visual, tem suporte a OpenGL, DirectX e Vulkan, ainda assim ele usa Windows API (Se a plataforma de destino for windows é claro).

Aqui esta um exemplo da janela principal de meu programa usando qt e seu editor visual:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

No C++ você não tem um toolkit de janela nativo. Cada fornecedor tem um, e tem alguns livres. Você pode experimentar o Qt que é bem difundido.

Comment: Gostaria de saber porque do voto negativo (para saber mesmo o que está de errado)